# Como usar uma função com parametros no atributo onclick do JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Estou começando a estudar JS e me deparei com um problema. Estou seguindo um tutorial para fazer um app de todo lists, e quando eu tentei criar uma função para deletar o todo tive um problema.

A função em questão deveria levar um parametro relacionado a posição do todo dentro de um vetor e assim ela poderia apaga-lo. Estou tentando fazer isso utilizando o setAttribute com um elemento de hiperlink (a), como eu mostro no código abaixo.

```
function mostrarItens() {
  for (var item of itens) {
    var itemElement = document.createElement("li");
    var itemText = document.createTextNode(item);
    itemElement.appendChild(itemText);

    var linkElement = document.createElement("a");
    var pos = itens.indexOf(item);
    linkElement.setAttribute("onclick", "remover(" + pos + ");");
    var linkText = document.createTextNode("Remover");
    linkElement.appendChild(linkText);
    linkElement.style.marginLeft = "5px";
    linkElement.setAttribute("href", "#");
    itemElement.appendChild(linkElement);

    ulElement.appendChild(itemElement);
  }
}

function remover(pos) {
  itens.splice(pos, 1);
  mostrarItens();
}
```

Sempre que eu clico no link criado para deletar a todo recebo um erro dizendo que a função remover não existe.

Gostaria de saber o que estou fazendo de erro. Já tentei varias coisas e até agora nada.

Desde já, muito obrigado.

Comment: `remover` é uma função declarada no escopo global, então ela deveria ser acessível pelo seu elemento. Por acaso esse código que você postou estaria dentro de algum escopo não global? Como por exemplo dentro de uma `IIFE`?

Comment: Olá João, cria por favor um exemplo com HTML que reproduza o problema aqui para te podermos ajudar.